# Remove all but specific part of image

Tags: python, image-processing, face-recognition

I am using Python face-recognition library to detect faces in an image, it returnes coordenates of faces in the image. i would like to delete all but the coordenates returned by the face-recognition function

```
import face_recognition

image1 = face_recognition.load_image_file("image extract/image.jpg")
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image1)
print(face_locations)
```

Comment: How many face locations do you expect to have?

Comment: between 1 and 3, depending on the image.

Comment: I guess you want to iterate over the face locations and find the minimum and maximum x, and the minimum and maximum y. Then you can extract your region of interest with `ROI = image[miny:maxy, minx:maxx]`

Comment: faceboxes from the face_locations normally are smaller then actual faces in "human" uderstanding. So, you'd better extract a region of interest with some margine: ROI = image[minx-delta:maxy-delta, maxx+delta:maxy+delta] but check to stay inside the image.

Comment: forgot to mention that i only plan to keep the biggest on., i will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to @Mark Setchell and @Bohdan 's help

```
    count2=0
    for file in image_folder:
        loc=f"image extract/frame{count2}.jpg"
        image1 = face_recognition.load_image_file("image extract/"+file)
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image1)
        width, height =0,0
        for face_location in face_locations:
            top, right, bottom, left = face_location
            face_image = image1[top+20:bottom+20, left+20:right+20]
            pil_image = Image2.fromarray(face_image)
            if (pil_image.size[0]*pil_image.size[1]>width*height):
                width, height = pil_image.size
                pil_image.save(loc)
```